# MKStore Manager

Tags: mkstorekit

how can i call [MKStoreManager sharedStorageManager] in applicationDidFinishLaunching

Answer (score 2):

You simply import MKStoreManager.h at the top of your app delegate.m file where applicationDidFinishLaunching is and then inside applicationDidFinishLaunching, add [MKStoreManager sharedManager], that will initialize it and start it

...this is assuming you have already filled in the necessary information in the MkStoreManager/Observer.h files

```
#import "MKStoreManager.h"

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    /* ...other code you want performed...*/
    [MKStoreManager sharedManager];
}
```

Note: the function header for applicationDidFinishLaunching that I wrote may be incomplete, meaning there might be a parameter...go look it up in the api, or have xcode auto fill it for you